# how to display categories for a specific post?

Tags: categories

for example : I have a Post Name computer and electronics and this post consist of two category 1.LED displays 2.Mobiles , now i want to display post = computer and electronics with it's specific categories.

Comment: Do you have custom taxonomy category ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [single_cat_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/) function to get category's name.

> Useful for category template files for displaying the category page title. The prefix does not automatically place a space between the prefix, so if there should be a space, the parameter value will need to have it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

for that purpose you need to use get_the_category($id) function, which accept the post id as parameter and return a list of terms object assigned to the passed post id, you can refer to this url to learn more.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/